# Custom Block Form Not redirecting to New Page

Tags: 7, webforms, redirection

I have created a form to take a node ID and then you select either edit or delete and then I would like it to go to 'node/[nid]/edit' or 'node/[nid]/delete' depending on the selection of the radio button.
Here is my code:

```
function edit_node_block_info(){
    $blocks['edit_node'] = array(
        'info' => t('Custom Block to allow edit/delete/copy'),
        'status' => 1,
        'region' => 'Primary',
        'weight' => 0,
        'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
    );

    return $blocks;
}
/*
 * Implements hook_block_view: sets how the block is displayed
 */
function edit_node_block_view($delta = ''){
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'edit_node' :
            $block['subject'] = t('Edit Nodes');
            $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('edit_node_form');
            break;
    }
    return $block;
}
/*
 * implements custom form/creating custom form for drupal_get_form named above.
 */

function edit_node_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['node-id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Enter the Node ID'),
        '#max-length' => 8,
        '#required' => 1,
    );
    $form['edit-node'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select Action'),
        '#options' => array(t('edit'), t('delete')),
        '#required' => 1,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function edit_node_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    $query = db_query('SELECT nid FROM {node}');
    foreach ($query as $result) {
        if (!($form_state['values']['node-id'] != $result)) {
            form_set_error('node-id', 'Node-id must match a current nid.');
        }
    }
}

function edit_node_submit($form, &$form_state){
    if (form_state['values']['edit-node'] == 'edit'){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . (form_state['values']['node-id']) . '/edit';
    }
    if (form_state['values']['edit-node'] == 'delete'){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . (form_state['values']['node-id']) . '/delete';
    }
}
```

In the $form array do I need some sort of redirect handler to make it work? Or a print_r or render?

I also tried `$link = (form_state['values']['node-id']);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue I was having was twofold. First I need to add some settings:

```
$form['node-action'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Select Action'),
        '#options' => array (
            edit => t('edit'),
            delete => t('delete'),
            add => t('add'),
            ),
        '#required' => 1,
    );
```

Then added:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#submit' => array('edit_node_submit'),
    );
```

And lastly my submit function:

```
function edit_node_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $node_id = $form_state['values']['node-id'];
    $node_action = ($form_state['values']['node-action']);
    $form_state['redirect'] = TRUE;
    if ($node_action == 'edit') {
        $form_state['redirect'] = ('node/' . $node_id . '/edit');
        }
    if ($node_action == 'delete'){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . $node_id . '/delete';
    }
    if ($node_action == 'add'){
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/hospitalist-schedule';
    }
}
```

Everything is working for the most part.